# prisma: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

[THIS IS THE ACTUAL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMicQ.png)

**This is my DTO**

```
export class CreateGradeDto {
  id: string;
  first_bimester?: number;
  second_bimester?: number;
  third_bimester?: number;
  fourth_bimester?: number;
  studentId: never;
  classId: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

**This is my prisma model**

```
model Grades {
  id              String   @id @unique
  first_bimester  Float
  second_bimester Float
  third_bimester  Float
  fourth_bimester Float
  student         Student  @relation(fields: [studentId], references: [id])
  studentId       String   @unique
  class           Classes  @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
  classId         String   @unique
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime @default(now())
}
```

**And this is the student model**

```
export class CreateStudentDto {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  cpf: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

(I'm using nestjs for this project)

i can't figure out why i can't save the grades, even knowing that all the time the id's are saved as string. I also checked the real postgre database and they are saved as strings.

Can someone help me??

Comment: Are you setting the id in the app instead of the db?

Comment: yes, im using v4 from uuid lib for id creation

Comment: You should have a mapping layer, don't just pass the dto to the db (for various reasons). It looks like prisma generates the types for you based on the model schema, which is why there's a type mismatch. See [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#type-definitions) for an example.

Comment: I think you need to create a new instance of that model, map the values from your dto to that instance, then pass that new instance to the create method. Or if you want it to be quick and dirty, your dto could extend that type.

Comment: i thought the best practice was by send the dto straight like this. thanks for the help, i'll try chaging it.

Comment: it depends on the frame of reference. if this is the model coming into an api from the client, I prefer the mapping layer. others may not.

Answer (score 17):

I couldn't initially figure out how to create a record and relate it to an existing record. I got the same error as you (well, `number is not assignable to type never` because my IDs are numeric).

Then I found the relevant part of the docs here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries/#connect-an-existing-record - it's not entirely front and centre. The syntax in your case would be something like:

```js
prisma.grade.create({
    data: {
      student: { connect: { id: 'your-student-id' } },
      // ... rest of the grade data
    },
  });
```

So, yes, you will need to do some sort of mapping to convert the relation fields in the DTO to the syntax above. Something like:

```js
// Create a copy of the dto data without the foreign key fields. Using lodash here for brevity
const gradeData = _.omit(createGradeDto, ['studentId', 'classId']);

prisma.grade.create({
    data: {
      ...gradeData,
      student: { connect: { id: createGradeDto.studentId } },
      class: { connect: { id: createGradeDto.classId } },
    },
  });
```

Comment: Without lodash version: ```const {studentId, classId, ...gradeData} = createGradeDto```

Answer (score -4):

All you need to do is enable strict in you tsconfig's compilerOptions like so

```js
{
     "compilerOptions": {
         "strict": true,
         ...
     },
     ...
}
```