# Prisma -> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I'm having an issue with this strange typescript error stating that type number is not assignable to type 'never'. I would normally be able to fix, but I'm not sure what's happening with the Prisma config in my nest js project.

Here is the code in my service file. It's strange, as I'm performing the exact same logic with very similar functions, and I've never seen this error before. I've run 'prisma generate' and 'prisma migrate dev', and can confirm all the generated types and DB are up to date.

Does anyone know what I'm overlooking? Thanks!

```
async create(input: CreateSongToListInput): Promise<SongToList> {
    const songToList = await this.db.songToList.create({
      data:
        song_id: input.song_id,
        list_id: input.list_id,
        movie_id: input.movie_id,
        tvshow_id: input.tvshow_id,
        order: input.order,
      },
    })
    return songToList
  }
```

My prisma schema is as follows

```
model SongToList {
  id           Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  list_id      Int
  list         List   @relation(fields: [list_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  song_id      Int
  song         Song   @relation(fields: [song_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  played_count Int    @default(0)
  movie_id     Int?
  movie        Movie? @relation(fields: [movie_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  tvshow_id    Int?
  tvshow       Show?  @relation(fields: [tvshow_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  order        Int?
  user_id      Int
  user         User   @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the error as text in the future :) Texted based stuff should generally not be posed as pictures. You may want to read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: So the issue is with the (probably) generated interface. I sadly don't have any prisma experience. That `Without<SongToListUncheckedCreateInp` (sadly the screenshot ends here) seems to exclude `song_id` and your currently trying to assign a number to it. Is it possible to post those type definitions?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/70268839/10315665 solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell me if works correctly

```
 async create(input: CreateSongToListInput): Promise < SongToList > {
    const songToList = await this.db.songToList.create({
            data: {
                songToList: {
                    create: {
                        song_id: input.song_id,
                        list_id: input.list_id,
                        movie_id: input.movie_id,
                        tvshow_id: input.tvshow_id,
                        order: input.order,

                    }
                },

            }
        }
    })
   return songToList
   }
```